# Remount all filesystems in fstab with new options

Tags: fstab

The `mount -a` command disregards mount options, which makes it useless when that's what you changed.

How to re-evaluate all the mount options in fstab as if rebooting?

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried the **remount** option?

```
mount -o remount -a
```

Should re-mount with the changed mount-options of your **fstab**.

Answer (score 0):

The manual way, as a `fish` multiliner:

```
cat /etc/fstab | while read dev mnt type opt dump pass
    if not string match noauto (string split , $opt)
        mount -o remount,$opt $mnt
    end
end
```

This assumes that the `noauto` mountpoints are not mounted.
Which is the case for me, as my backup disks are normally unmounted.

Comment: it also assumes there are no comments in your fstab file or spaces in your mount point.